# Jquery Load function not working in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, android, html, mobile

So I'm trying to pull the content of a div from one webpage into a div on our mobile page using the load function. On my desktop browser, all is well. Code pulls all info I need perfectly. But for some reason, while testing on my android browser, it doesn't pull the info. Instead, there's some text on the bottom left of the screen that says "loading" but nothing ever loads. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using on the site :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('#newevents').load('http://www.kobebistro.com/5/special.php #events'); });</script>
```

you can check out the [full site/source code](http://www.kobebistro.com/5/mobile/events2.html)

I've been stuck for the last couple of days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem (at least why you see the 'loading' text) is due to the CSS file for jQuery Mobile not being added to your page. The "loading" text that you see at the bottom is actually the jQuery Mobile page transitioning/loading.

Add the following stylesheet link to the top of your pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively hide using the following CSS rule to your existing stylesheet:

```
.ui-loader {
    display: none;
}
```

I have setup an example which works for me on both Desktop (tested on Firefox and Chrome) and on Android Mobile browser (2.3):
http://www.jonwarner.net/stackoverflow/10940849/mobile/index.htm

I would also recommend that you check out page creation via the following on page anatomy:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

<strike>Do you see any alert if you use the following code?</strike>

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ alert('document ready called'); });</script>
```

Moving on from the above, consider adding a callback and checking the response:

```
$("#newevents").load("http://www.kobebistro.com/5/special.php#events", function(response, status, xhr) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
});
```

JSFiddle setup to hopefully help you resolve the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/X3B6t/1/

Comment: yeah, pop up shows "document ready called" on both desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: Is your code calling the load() from the same domain (just different pages)?

Comment: yeah, same domain... different folders though

Comment: So I replaced my script with your load script and nothing was loaded on both my desktop or my phone and I didn't get any alerts either. Can you can check my coding to see if I have it set up right? I feel like maybe I'm missing something. And by the way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you able to create a new php page called 'newevents.php' that could be targeted to return exactly what needs to be fed down to the mobile page rather than a section of an existing page? Have you tried requesting a more basic page?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a targeted page like that? Do you mean creating a webpage that doesn't have anything but the contents of the div I want and have it sent to both my original site and the mobile site? And also I just saved the "special.php" page as a basic html page "special.html", but it still only works on my desktop pc and not on my mobile phone.

Comment: Ok, so I created a 'targeted page' which contains nothing but the contents of the "events" div (http://www.kobebistro.com/5/special55.html) and tried loading it into my mobile site (http://www.kobebistro.com/5/mobile/events2.html). Same result, it works on my desktop but not my mobile phone.

Comment: I just realized another problem... although the events div loads on my desktop browser, the links in the rest of the page are rendered useless. Ugh

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yes as you have setup, just a simple page that only returns the events that you can use to populate both sides. To fix the links you'll probably want to output the full paths for the links (e.g. href="entertainment.php" would become href="www.kobebistro.com/5/entertainment.php").

Comment: ok, will do. But still no solution. Is it because mobile browsers don't support the load function? What could it possibly be?

Comment: I don't see why not, load is simply calling get() then setting the html of the selected element ('#newevents') to the returned results. And to my knowledge mobile browsers do not have issues with ajax calls.

Comment: load Definitely works (maybe the document ready is the wrong place?), see: http://webhole.net/2009/06/13/ajax-page-loading-with-jquery/ and http://demo.webhole.net/load-a-page-with-jquery/ (I tested the demo on my android device and it works fine)

Comment: Solution: For mobile browsers, the page with the source data not only has to be on the same server, but also must be in the exact same folder as the page calling the data. This is not true for desktop browsers. So what I'm going to do is have a targeted file in the 'mobile' folder where the mobile site can pull from and the desktop version can pull from as well. Negative is that if anyone using a mobile phone browser looks at the normal webpage, they will not see the data.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back that up? See my updated example, the sample data is pulled from the folder above 'mobile'. Tested on Android 2.3.6 (Galaxy Note). The main reason you see the text saying 'loading' is that you have not included the jQuery Mobile css file and do not use 'data-role="page"' - i.e. not correctly using jQuery mobile.